# using a single folder for 2 times on same drive

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have two websites pointing to two different folders on the same drive under the inetpub/wwwroot binded to the coldfusion server which is configured with IIS . The directories which one is called

**abc** and other is called **xyz**

i want to use a site wide error handler for both the sites which i have specified as `errors/mypage.cfm`

now errors is a complete different folder which runs on the cferror exception which i had defined it in the Application.cfm of the abc folder

i want the errors folder file should run on both the sites and it should the errors for both the sites

what should be my trick here, am using `coldfusion 11`

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate location in your IIS webroot for the site wide error handler. Then create an IIS alias for each site that points to that location. Then in the CFAdmin setup the site wide error handler to point to that location. In the server.xml create a ColdFusion alias.

Example:

- Your webroot is: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\
- Error handler location: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\500errors\
- IIS Alais: 500errors --> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\500errors\
- CFAdmin setting: /500errors

Add this line to your server.xml in the HOST section and adjust it for your specific paths.

```
<Context path="/" docBase="C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot" WorkDir="C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\runtime\conf\Catalina\localhost\tmp" aliases="/500errors=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\500errors\" />
```

Comment: ok, i will try its a live site but, i have another idea, rather than making IIS settings, can i just keep my errors folder outside the folders root like wwwroot/errors and then in the cfadmin i can just point to them

Comment: That's exactly what my example does. But it also serves as a IIS server wide custom error handler too.  You can just skip the IIS alias. But all the other steps are needed.

Comment: if i skip the IIS, i do not think i need to make any modifications in the XMl File as you did

Comment: ColdFusion requires the Site-Wide error handler to be a relative path from the ColdFusion web root.  The default ColdFusion web root is C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot.  If you put your error handler in that folder then you do not need to update the XML file. If you put it somewhere else then you do.  BTW: I never recommend serving any code from the ColdFusion web root for basic security concerns.

Comment: Please see my previous comment. It specifies when you do or don't need to edit the server.xml file.

Comment: You explained in a very difficult Manner, I might have forgot to tell that I am no Expert IN IIS. now even i have a site configured, if i do add a subdomain like: errors.mysite.com and asign it any IP, it does not work, going to the steps from 2nd onwards does not make any sense to me and you did not even told me that do i need to create alais inside the website which i had declared under IIS or a different website completely, you might have explained in your post but you tried to fit big information in a very small piece and i am no good at interpreting it, so please if you can explain better

Comment: that will be good and i expect an answer which should be clear and tells if i need to create a subdomain anywhere else before i can use in IIS or if yes, do i need to configure its DNS Name records, because this all seems very complicated

Comment: how you are editing xml and where it is and why we edit it